# Worker from imported NPM module causing jest tests to fail

Tags: unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I installed [browser-image-compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-image-compression) which, as part of its functionality, creates a Worker. Now when I run jest tests, I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

There are no tests connected to the function which uses browser-image-compression.

The scripts section in package.json has the following two lines

```
"test": "react-scripts test",
"test:ci": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test"
```

Oh, and I have a file for setting up tests. Should I mock Worker in here?

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import '@domain/yup';

configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});

global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late in responding to this but it could help others - but following this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3449#issuecomment-347337666) helped me with this issue.

If you add the following to its own file - I have mine within the same `dir` as the `setupTests` file named `workerMock.js`:

```
export default class Worker {
  constructor(stringUrl) {
    this.url = stringUrl;
    this.onmessage = () => {};
  }

  postMessage(msg) {
    this.onmessage(msg);
  }
}
```

Then import that `Worker` file into your test setup file and add `window.Worker = Worker`. Your setup file may look like:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import '@domain/yup';

import Worker from 'path-to-your-worker-file-above';

configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});

global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');

window.Worker = Worker;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is that updating 'browser-image-compression' package to the latest version ,  this helped me .